# How do I get text in my collapsed menu button to be right of my icon?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navber that when viewed on a mobile device collapses into a button to open the menu.

It's fairly standard. A working demo can be viewed here.

http://www.bootply.com/SyDERpkfFY

Instead of just having a button with an icon, I would like "Menu Options" text next to it.

However, I seem to only be able to put the text below the icon bar. How can I put the text so that it is to the right of the icon?

Below is what I have so far. If you look at my demo, the menu options text appears below the icon, I would like it to appear to the right.

```
<div class="navbar-header pull-left">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="navbar-text"> Menu Options</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
```

Comment: I don't see the text in the demo you provided.

Comment: Same here. Demo looks like it's for something else entirely.

Comment: xHocquet : The text only appears when you're rendering it in the mobile view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the icon in a new parent span

```
   <span class="menu-icon">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </span>
```

And add this to the css:

```
.menu-icon {float: left;}
```

This makes all the icon float to the left as a whole block.

It works because by default the elements are stacked one over the other unless you make them float somewhere (left or right typically). As you want the whole icon to be placed on the left you need to add a container for the whole icon and then make that container float to the left.

Comment: Oh wow, this works! - ok can you please explain how this works? I don't even really understand why all the spans appear below each other in that div.

Comment: I added a deeper explanation

Answer (score 1):

you should add span container to icons.

```
<div class="navbar-header pull-left">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
         <span style="float:left; margin: 2px 10px 0 0;">
             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </span>
         <span class="navbar-text"> Menu Options</span>
    </button>
</div>
```